# Do I need a DependencyResolver in my MVC/MEF app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mef

I've seen articles online about how to implement them, but I still don't understand exactly what they do, and if I need one in my application. My application will have a `HostApp` that has many plugins with controllers and views in them. Will I need a custom `DepedencyResolver` in my app?

**If you have any questions please let me know! Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't 'need' one. If you want to use dependency injection, MVC allows you to hook up a resolver so you can inject dependencies at various points, most typically is injecting some dependency into your controller.

```
public class CustomerController
{
 public CustomerController(ICustomerRepository repository)
 {
 }
}
```

It's up to you to use it or not if your application calls for it. This depends on how you have your layers and dependencies setup, but you dont 'need' it, but it can help in many cases.

Check out Dependency Injection in .Net by Mark Seeman for the best ref on the subject. Many questions could be asked about your implementation since you may have plugins and optional dependencies which is a bit out of the scope of the question but feel free to post more : )

http://manning.com/seemann/